# HTML/CSS: How can I get a box with a single border?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need a simple list (3 lines of text) surrounded by a gray box. I know I need to implement on blur instead of a "close" button. 
Here's what I have so far...
I can't sen to get text values to transfer.
Help!

```
<script> function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); } </script>
<input name="media" id="media" type="text" />
<input type="button" value="..." 
    onclick="$('keypad').style.display='inline-block';"/>
<div id="keypad" style="display:none; background:#CCC; vertical-align:top;">
<input type="text" value="Canvas" onclick="$('media').value='Canvas';"/><br/>
<input type="button" value="Done" onclick="$('keypad').style.display='none'"/>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with `border: 1px solid gray`?

Comment: Actually, after running your sample html, I don't see the relationship between the code and your question

Comment: OMG! this is a ripped version of a response I posted a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549359/how-to-fill-up-numbers-in-a-form-field-via-a-popup-key-padusing-javascript-ajax/1562027#1562027
 Look at the $() function, styles and id's LOL!

Answer (score 1):

You're mimicking the Prototype framework but could be getting much more out of it. Firstly, if you'd set your click/blur events up as abstracted events the code would be clearer and more cross-browser compatible.

If you're showing/hiding an element use

```
$('elementID').show();
$('elementID').hide();
```

If you're getting a form value use:

```
$F('elementID');
```

or setting a form value:

```
$F('elementID') = 'newValue';
```

I can't really understand what you're trying to do - your question re: '3 lines of text' doesn't really reflect the code you've posted...

Answer (score 0):

```
<script> function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); } </script>
<input name="media" id="media" type="text" />
<input type="button" value="..." onclick="$('keypad').style.display='inline-block';"/>
<div id="keypad" onmouseout="$('keypad').style.display='none'" style="display:none; background:#CCC; vertical-align:top;border:1px solid grey;">
<input type="text" value="Canvas" onclick="$('media').value = $('mediain').value;" id="mediain" onblur="$('keypad').style.display='none'"/><br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
border: 1px solid black;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean about getting text values to transfer, but a box with a single gray border should just be

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;">
<!-- your list here -->
</div>
```

I spent too long typing, I'll just refer you to adam's answer for the logic part of your question.